# No module named _import_tools

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, python-import

I am maintaining an Anaconda python environment and ran across the following problem when importing numpy:

```
In [1]: import numpy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5a0bd626bb1d> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy

*/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    138     from .version import version as __version__
    139 
--> 140     from ._import_tools import PackageLoader
    141 
    142     def pkgload(*packages, **options):

ImportError: No module named _import_tools
```

Before this occurred I had installed pytorch and updated tensorflow. But these specific modules are unlikely to be the cause for these errors, unless one of them attempted to update numpy.

numpy version: 1.11.3

Anaconda version: 4.3.1

iPython version: 5.1.0

Has someone seen this before and knows the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the cause, but it can be solved with the force-reinstall option of `conda`:

```
conda update -f numpy
```